# Prove the Polygon with a maximum area for given perimeter P is concave and non--self-intersecting.

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, proof-writing

I am trying to prove that for a given polygon, $Q$ with a fixed perimeter, $P$, such that no other polygon with a perimeter $P$ has an area larger than $Q$, $Q$ is non-self-intersecting and concave. I have attempted this proof and I have attached my proof below. The worries I have with proof is that I may have misused real-analysis as I am just learning this branch of mathematics and that the proof is not rigorous, especially the part about self-intersections. I am quite sure there are more elegant proofs as well. Please can someone comment on the validity of my attempt and address my expressed concerns, and potentially provide a more elegant proof. Here is my attempt:

Let X be the set of points in $\Bbb (\Bbb R^2)^N$ that describe the vertices of a directed polygon (May have side lengths of $0$ and self-intersections) with perimeter $P$ and one vertex at $(0;0)$. If vertices are defined by the vector $(x;y)$, then  $x^2+y^2≤P^2$, so $X$ is both bounded and closed. ⸫ $X$ is compact. The function $A(z)$, which determines the area of the polygon defined by the vector $z$, is therefore continuous on $X$ and, by the Extreme Value Theorem, $A$ will have a maximum on $X$.

Polygon $Q$ is described by the vector $q$, where $q∈X$, and $A(q)$ is the maximum of $A$ on $X$.

We continue by proving $Q$ is concave.

Let $Q$ be convex. $Q$ will, therefore, have three vertices:  $D$, $E$ and $F$ such that $DÊF_interior>\pi$. Let vector $f$, where $f∈X$, exist such that $f⊂q$, and $f$ contains all elements of $q$ except for $E$. Let $h$ be the perpendicular height of $∆DEF$. We have:
$$A(q)=A(f)-1/2 DF∙h $$
Move $E$ to preserve $ED+EF$, but make $DÊF_interior<\pi$. We have:
$$A(q)=A(f)+1/2 DF∙h$$
Since $1/2 DF∙h>0$, $A(q)$ has increased by altering one vertex, and hence we have a contradiction since $A(q)$ is the maximum of $A$ on $X$.
Therefore, Q is concave.

We will now prove Q is not self-intersecting, making use of Signed Area.

Let $Q$ be self-intersecting. $Q$ will, therefore, have three vertices: $D$,$E$ and $F$ such that $Area(∆DEF)<0$. This means the Area of $∆DEF$ does not constitute as part of the area of Q.
Create a new polygon, $Y$, described by vector $y$, $y∈X$, such that $y$ contains all elements of $q$, but $DE$ and $EF$ do not form sides of $Y$; instead, $y$ contains a new point, $O$, which is constructed such that $DO$ and $FO$ are now sides of $Y$ with $DO+FO=DE+EF$, and $Area(∆DOF)>0$. Note, y still contains point $E$, as other segments may branch off $E$. We have changed the direction of points $D$ and $F$ such that $Area(∆DOF)$ constitutes as the area of $Y$.  $Y$ will have the same number of sides of $Q$ and the perimeters will be the same. $g$ is the vector that describes polygon $DEFO$.
$$A(y)=A(q)+A(g)$$
where $A(g) > 0$
$$∴A(y)>A(q).$$
∴ We have a contradiction as $A(q)$ is the maximum of $A$ on $X$. Therefore $Q$ is not self-intersecting.

Comment: As a big fun of geometry (go check Geometry Now on YouTube :)) I'm guessing that the polygon with greatest area ocurrs when all the vertices are concyclic.... which sounds 'fun' to give a shot...

Comment: You are correct, I have a proof for that as part of a larger proof that the polygon is regular. However, my proof relies on the fact that the polygon is concave, which is why I'm posting the question.

Comment: I must add though, that I thought that the question had the condition of every side having fixed length... which is a slightly different situation